# Add/remove class on click - how do I remove the class on a second click area?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a menu with a dropdown, where the LI element gets an activeclass on click. I have, after a lot if struggle, managed to set a script that sets an active class to an  div that I have hidden, which shows on the click as an overlay of the site (under the dropdown). everything works as It should, except if I click outside the dropdown to close it instead of clicking the menubutton. This doesnt change my overlay div's class- how do I change my script to work on clicks outside the dropdown aswell, and what should I target here?

The hidden div:

```
<div id="site-overlay"></div>
```

script:

```
$.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('li').on('click', function(){
        if(jQuery(this).hasClass('active')) {
            jQuery("#site-overlay").addClass("active");
        } else {
            jQuery("#site-overlay").removeClass("active");
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: can you provide fiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work:

```
$.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('li').on('click', function () {
        if (jQuery(this).hasClass('active')) {
            jQuery("#site-overlay").addClass("active");
        } else {
            jQuery("#site-overlay").removeClass("active");
        }
    });

    jQuery("#site-overlay").click(function () {
        jQuery(this).removeClass("active");
    });
});
```

Notice the new event handler.

Comment: That worked perfect, and was exactly how i figured it would be written. I wasnt able to write in the second handler though, very new to javascript and jquery. very logical, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can add a click event to the document body and then check the click location:

```
$(document).click(function(event) { 
    if(!$(event.target).closest('#site-overlay').length) {
        if($('#site-overlay').is(":visible")) {
            $('#site-overlay').hide()
        }
    }        
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery('li').on('click', function(){
    ...
}
```

This executes only when you click on 'li' element.
But what about clicking outside 'li' element?
Try to add or replace:

```
jQuery('body').on('click', function(){
    if(jQuery('.megamenu li').hasClass('active')) {
        jQuery("#site-overlay").addClass("active");
    } else {
        jQuery("#site-overlay").removeClass("active");
    }
}
```